# Protect routes react router dom 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a route ('profile/edit') that edits some information, and I want to prevent the user from reaching it by typing in the URL. For example, I want if the user types [www.mywebsite.com/profile/edit/](http://www.mywebsite.com/profile/edit/) in the URL, it will get redirected to [www.mywebsite.com/](http://www.mywebsite.com/). So I only want it to be accessible when you click the edit button. How do I do this? I'm using react route 6 for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Is this URL accessible only if logged in?

Or do you need any param values to edit?

If yes, please double check your implementation, there you have other best methods to do it

**Answer**

Call a useNavigate in one of your root component (inside useEffect which only call once)

```
//rootComponent
const navigate = useNavigate()

useEffect(()=> {
   navigate('/')
), [])
//Rest of your code
```

Comment: I tried this: 
    useEffect(()=>{
      checkIfToken()

    }, [])
 

  function checkIfToken() {
    console.log("test");
    if (quoteToUpdate == null) {
      navigate('/')
    }
  };

But it looks like my useEffect never runs. It keeps telling me thatquoteToUpdate is null

Comment: so you need to check the token.

Comment: protect al the routes that is the best method

Comment: only render routes if token is available